# How to build a timer in google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have this timer I wrote myself but its way too complicated and then when I need to get back to it to re-use it I already forgot how it works and always takes some time to understand. For sure there must be a simpler way to do it.

Here it is:

```
=IF(((E4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1))+TIME($K$9,0,0))<NOW(),"RENT", IF((TRUNC(((iferror(datedif(NOW(), E4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1), "d"),""))-TIME((24-(text(E4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1) - NOW() - int(E4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1) - NOW())+TIME($K$9,0,0), "HH"))),0,0))) - 365 * iferror(datedif(NOW(), E4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1), "y"),""))<(1),"",(TRUNC(((iferror(datedif(NOW(), E4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1), "d"),""))-TIME((24-(text(E4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1) - NOW() - int(E4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1) - NOW())+TIME($K$9,0,0), "HH"))),0,0))) - 365 * iferror(datedif(NOW(), E4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1), "y"),""))&"d ")&(TEXT((E4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1))-(now()-TIME($K$9,0,0)),"HH""h"" mm""m""")))
```

The "d" from days needs to disappear when ETA is less than 24h.

Is there a cleaner simpler way to do this?

My file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: whats this for: IF(((E4/86400+DATE(1970,1,1))+TIME($K$9,0,0))<NOW(),"RENT"

Comment: Ah ok I forgot that part. It is to correct the time difference between my local time and the local time from the app. Atm it is 2 hours. I forgot to take it out of the formula for Stackoverflow. But right now as K9 is empty maybe it's at zero. Then the condition "<" is to activate "RENT". When ETA is met/over it displays "RENT". Could be something else like "ARRIVED" or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unix input countdown:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(E4/86400+25569-NOW(), 
           "\"&INT(E4/86400+25569-NOW())&"\d h\h m\m"), "0d ", )
```

[image]